# not reading an entire datagram from a UDP socket

Tags: sockets, networking, udp

What happens when you attempt to `recv` from a socket into a buffer that isn't big enough to store an entire datagram? Will as much of the datagram that can be stored be `recv`'d? Will the rest be lost? Or will it be returned on a subsequent call to `recv`?

Is there a way to ensure that entire datagrams are read regardless of their size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, (certianly on Windows/Linux), a datagram is truncated to fit into the passed buffer and the remaining data is lost permanently.

> Is there a way to ensure that entire datagrams are read regardless of
>   their size?

Use a 64K buffer. The UDP protocol ensures that datagrams cannot be larger than that, so all datagrams succesfully received will be read completely regardless of their size.

Comment: +1. In fact 65507 is sufficient unless you're dealing with IPv6.

Comment: @EJP - can't be assed over 28 bytes:)

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. If you attempt to `send` more than 64K will the data be split into multiple datagrams, or will the operation fail?

Comment: The UDP sendto, (or whatever), call will fail with an error return or an exception.  No datagram wil be sent.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform.  Systems that adhere to the Single Unix Specification (*e.g.*, Linux) will truncate the datagram to fit and discard the remainder.